# Getting 404 GET /contents.js with Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am unable to run Jupyter Notebook from my local directory due to a 404 Not Found error.

Below is what I get from cmd when running

```
[W 11:14:30.524 NotebookApp] 404 GET /contents.js (::1) 30.000000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree?
token=e49e29c7dcac8e08dc2da577daf592dc2fea9dd958adee64
```

The web page opens normally yet nothing showed up, and below is what I get form my browser's console

[image]

This is not my first time using Jupyter Notebook; it works all fine before, and this issue just appeared suddenly since yesterday, though I do not remember doing anything that can potentially crash the application.
I have tried re-install Anaconda yet it didn't help. Anyone knows how to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue today and I can see that maybe the solution is the same for you.
I don't know for which reason happens, but realize that in the url that forms the jupyter notebook when you do the command, between '/tree' and the '?token...' there is any slash '/' as there is in the logs that tell you how to open the notebook.

So the solution I found is to add the / like this: `/tree/?token=...`

I think this should be resolved in a next jupyter update.

Comment: The slash shouldn't make a difference at all, but for some reason changing just any character in the URL seems to fix the issue. As I commented on a different answer, this reeks of some weird browser caching behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was caused by an upgrade of my browser (Chromium-based).
Therefore, downgrading solved the problem.

Comment: Could you include information on what the version was previously, and what version you downgraded to?

Answer (score 0):

In my case issue was resolved, just by changing the token value in the URL, as your URL is:

`http://localhost:8888/tree?token=e49e29c7dcac8e08dc2da577daf592dc2fea9dd958adee64`

Change it to:

`http://localhost:8888/tree? token=e49e29c7dcac8e08dc2da577daf592dc2fea9dd958adee61`

or change any value in token you will have your jupyter working.
I don't know what but there is a bug in the data storage of tokens in the server-side of the Jupyter environment.

Comment: For whatever reason this fixed my issue, which happened after I rebooted due to a MacOS update (no changes otherwise). I removed the last character of the token (just to change anything at all) and reloaded the page, and boom the notebook environment loaded. What's more, it also fixed the jupyter lab environment I launched afterwards. No idea what's going on here, but my money's on a browser caching issue.